# Can UITextChecker access Thesaurus instead of Dictionary?

Tags: swift, uitextchecker

I'm aware that UITextChecker is used to check for misspelled words, but can it be used to access the Thesaurus? For example, how can I check if a string is similar to another string. For example:

Is "Car" similar to "Vehicle".

Does iOS have a native thesaurus that can be used like the dictionary UITextChecker. If so how can it be accessed?

This isn't a post seeking recommendations, but rather asking if a native functionality exists within the iOS SDK, and if so, what can be used to access it (i.e UITextChcker).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this after no responses and my own research was: no. UITextChecker is just mainly used for spelling mistakes.

I've had to create my own Thesaurus and build my own class to check words against each other.